# Seleccionar todas las filas de datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Quiero agregar un *checkTodo* que marque todas las filas de un *datatable*. Cada fila tiene su propio *checkbox* que se renderiza de acuerdo a un atributo llamado 'seleccionable'. Por el momento logre totalizar la cantidad de comprobante seleccionables y la sumatoria de los montos pero me falta localizar el *check* individual para poder marcarlo y agregarle la clase 'selected' a las filas correspondientes.

Dejo mi código a ver si alguien puede ayudarme

```
function obtener_comprobantes_actualizados(idcuenta, ids, ids2, ids3) {
    var cant = 0;
    var monto = 0;
    $("#pnlDeuda").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "obtenerDeuda",
        data: { 'idCuenta': idcuenta, 'idSubsistema': ids, 'idSubsistema2': ids2, 'idSubsistema3': ids3 },
        success: function (data) {

            var dataTableVariable = $("#tbComp").DataTable({
                "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;

                    var intVal = function (i) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ?
                            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                            typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                    };

                    total = api
                        .column(6)
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0);

                    $("#deudaTotal").text("Deuda Total $ " + total);
                },
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 15], [10, 15]],
                "searching": false,
                destroy: true,
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    { 'data': 'idComprobante' },
                    {
                        'data': "seleccionable",
                        "searchable": false,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            if (data === 1) {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" id="chkFila" />';
                            } else {
                                return '';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    { 'data': 'ano' },
                    { 'data': 'cuota' },
                    { 'data': 'fecVtoForm' },
                    { 'data': 'dsEstadoComp' },
                    { 'data': 'totalActual' },
                ],
                columnDefs: [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
            }],
                "language": { "sUrl": "fonts/datatable_espanol.txt" }
            });
            bServerSide: true;
            bProcessing: true;

            $('#tbComp tbody').off('click');
            $('#tbComp tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                $("#frmpago").hide();
                let sel = dataTableVariable.row(this).data().seleccionable;
                let ch = $(this).find("#chkFila");

                if (sel == 0) {
                    alertify.error("Comprobante no seleccionable");
                } else {
                    let imp_comp = dataTableVariable.row(this).data().totalActual;

                    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                        $(this).removeClass('selected');
                        monto -= parseFloat(imp_comp);
                        $("#monto").html("Monto a pagar $ " + monto.toFixed(2));
                        cant -= 1;
                        $("#cant").html("Comprobantes Seleccionados: " + cant);
                        ch.prop('checked', false);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).addClass('selected');
                        monto += parseFloat(imp_comp);
                        $("#monto").html("Monto a pagar $ " + monto.toFixed(2));
                        cant += 1;
                        $("#cant").html("Comprobantes Seleccionados: " + cant);
                        ch.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#chkTodo').change(function () {
                monto = 0;
                cant = 0;

                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    var data = dataTableVariable.rows().data();

                    data.each(function (value, index) {
                        if (value.seleccionable === 1) {
                            monto += value.totalActual;
                            cant++;
                            // check checkbox y addClass('selected')
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (cant > 0) {
                    $("#monto").html("Monto a pagar $ " + monto.toFixed(2));
                    $("#cant").html("Comprobantes Seleccionados: " + cant);
                } else {
                    $("#monto").html("");
                    $("#cant").html("");
                }
            })

        }, error: function () {
            alertify.alert("Ha ocurrido un problema")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final use el siguiente codigo, el propuesto por cooper no me servia porque necesitaba pintar las filas seleccionables

```
$('#chkTodo').change(function () {
            monto = 0;
            cant = 0;

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#tbComp tbody tr').each(function () {
                    let sel = dataTableVariable.row(this).data().seleccionable;

                    if (sel == 1) {
                        $(this).addClass('selected');
                        let ch = $(this).find("#chkFila");
                        ch.prop('checked', true);
                        let amount = dataTableVariable.row(this).data().totalActual;
                        cant++;
                        monto += amount;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#tbComp tbody tr').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                    let ch = $(this).find("#chkFila");
                    ch.prop('checked', false);
                });
            }

            totalizar();
        })

        function totalizar() {
            if (cant > 0) {
                $("#monto").html("Monto a pagar $ " + monto.toFixed(2));
                $("#cant").html("Comprobantes Seleccionados: " + cant);
            } else {
                $("#monto").html("");
                $("#cant").html("");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ponle a tus input checkbox una clase y en el evento click sobre el input "checkTodo", seleccionado todos los checkbox con dicha clase.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){+

  $('#checkTodo').click(function(){
    $('.checkbox').prop('checked',true);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkTodo">

<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="chek_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="chek_2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="chek_3">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="chek_4">
```

Comment: Necesito pintar las filas (addClass('selected')) por ende ese codigo no me serviria. Muchas Gracias de todas formas. Te invito a inspeccionar el codigo que acabo de publicar como respuesta